# TikZ: Label nodes on to path

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, labels

I use the `to` syntax to set a node in the horizontal middle between to other nodes. My problem is, that a label does not fit well at this middle node. Compare the label of node 2 and node 3 in the picture:

[image]

Here is the corresponding mwe:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{myRec/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=5mm, minimum width=5mm}}

    \node (nd1) [myRec] {1};
    \node (nd2) [myRec, below right=of nd1, label=above:x] {2};

    \path (nd2) to node (nd3) [myRec, label=above:x] {3} (nd2 -| nd1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use the label, because I created an own shape which needs to be on the horizontal position of node 2.

Comment: Instead of using a  `to` path to place the node, you could simply load `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and place the node using `\node [myRec, label=above:x] (nd3) at ($(nd2)!0.5!(nd2 -| nd1)$) {3};`. That way, the `label` is placed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jake already proposed a solution in his comment, but here you have another one.

```
\path (nd1.east|-nd2) -- (nd2.west) node[pos=0.5, myRec, label={above:x}] (nd3) {3};
```

or

```
\path (nd1|-nd2) -- (nd2.center) node[pos=0.5, myRec, label={above:x}] (nd3) {3};
```

Both will place a node with it's `center` into the middle of an horizontal line between
`n1` and `n2`.

By the way, I'm using CVS version and I've no problem with node 3 label.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{myRec/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=5mm, minimum width=5mm}}

    \node (nd1) [myRec] {1};
    \node (nd2) [myRec, below right=of nd1, label=above:x] {2};

%\path (nd2) to node (nd3) [myRec, label=above:x] {3} (nd2 -| nd1);

    \path (nd1.east|-nd2) -- (nd2.west) node[pos=0.5, myRec, label={above:x}, anchor=center] (nd3) {3};

%\path (nd1|-nd2) -- (nd2.center) node[pos=0.5, myRec, label={above:x}, anchor=center] (nd3) {3};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ignasi! What has CVS to do with the positioning of the label? Btw.: I use the `midway` command, but that is equal to `pos=0.5`.

Comment: @Dirk I'm not sure, but I've found this sentence in `changes.log`: "Fixed bug #126 "Incorrect placed labels for implicite positioned nodes."" In any case, both provided solutions place labels correctly even with CTAN version.